# Cleaner way to bind a function to this?

Tags: javascript, bind

I've got lots of code that does stuff like the following to bind a callback to `this`:

```
someMethod: function()
{
  this.doSomething({
    callback: function(a,b,c)
    {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(this.title);
    }.bind(this),
    otherData: [1,2,3,4],
    anotherOption: true
  });
}

title:'test',
```

I'd like this to be more readable, and encapsulate how I do my binding to this - through a function call or something similar... something like the following pseudocode (which I know wouldn't work):

```
someMethod: function()
{
  this.doSomething({
    callback: this.bind(a,b,c)
    {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(this.title);
    },
    otherData: [1,2,3,4],
    anotherOption: true
  });
},

title:'test',
```

Is there anyway to bind a callback to this that's more readable? Note that my example above is simplified - often I might have 2 callbacks being passed in, as well as other options as well.

Comment: Why exactly are you passing the callback as an object, and not just a function directly ?

Comment: You're probably over-using `bind` if you want a more succinct way of doing that... In your example, I would expect `this.doSomething` to provide a context for the callback, using `callback.apply(this, ...)`, instead of just invoking `callback()`.

Comment: Personally, I think the first form is more readable than the second, especially when using four spaces instead of two.

Comment: @meagar - Over using it... how? I'd like my callbacks to execute on my main class - for example, my class (for lack of a better term) wraps 2 third party libs that use callbacks - i want all the callbacks to execute in the context of my class. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @adeneo: Usually the objects passed in are more complex than just a callback. I added in more options to make this clearer! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how `….bind(this)` is not readable. It won't get any shorter (OK, a global function `bind(this,…)` would save one char). What's wrong?

Comment: I'd still pass the callback directly, and then just add arguments for other stuff, something like `doSomething(object, function() { //callback })`

Comment: @BradParks As above, in my first comment: If you're the author of `doSomething`, it should be passing the context along to the callback. Your library should assume that people want a sane context passed to their callback functions. Backbone for example, insures that view/model callbacks are always executed with the correct context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would create the callback method then assign it, I find it less painful to read and if needed it also leave you a reference of the function which can be useful when using `bind` with event handlers for example (can add/remove them) as `bind` returns a function.

```
someMethod: function() {

  var callback = function(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(this.title);
  }.bind(this);

  this.doSomething({
    callback: callback 
  });
},

title:'test',
```

You could also not use `bind` at all and like many JS methods take an argument which is the scope of your callback so basically just adding a new property to your object `scope: this`. Ideally callback should be run using `call` which take the scope as first argument.

Comment: Nice suggestion actually!

Comment: I've done this in the past - but then it tends to separate the callback from all the other options - if possible, I like to leave the callback in the context of the other options, so it's clear who owns it. But this is probably what I'll do when it gets too messy... thanks!

Comment: The callback reference is still in the same object that in your code and is still accessible the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
someMethod : function ()
{
    var that = this;
    this.doSomething({
        callback : function (a,b,c) {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(that);
        }
    });
}
```

There is no need for `.bind` if you are creating a new function each time anyway. Local variables are more suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use something like:

```
 //...
 someMethod: function() {
  this.doSomething({
    boundTo: this, //<= here
    callback: function(a,b,c) {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(this.boundTo.title); //<= and here
    },
    otherData: [1,2,3,4],
    anotherOption: true
   })
  }
 // ...
```

Or this (closure) should work too

```
someMethod: function() {
  this.doSomething({
    callback: function(self) {
                return function(a,b,c) {
                  console.log(a);
                  console.log(self.title);
                 }; 
              }(this),
    otherData: [1,2,3,4],
    anotherOption: true
   });
}
```

Comment: Like I suggested at the bottom of my post, I prefer to use `scope` but `bountTo` is quite good suggestion too.